# Where to get OPCAutomation.dll and OPCEnumLib.dll

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, opc

Where can I download OPCAutomation.dll and OPCEnumLib.dll?
I am working on this web app that references "Interop.OPCAutomation.dll" and "Interop.OpcEnumLib.dll"

Got below error upon creating instance of OPCServerClass.
My employer cannot provide copy of those DLL and the regsvr32 does not work for "Interop" DLL files. I am wondering if its freely distributed.

*Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID  {28E68F9A-8D75-11D1-8DC3-3C302A000000}  failed due to the following error:  80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).*

Answer (score 1):

You should find them from the OPC Foundation web site:

https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/samples-and-tools-classic

Check the Automation Wrapper for these DLLs.

Comment: Thanks alot Jouni! What should I use for a developer machine?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. In fact it might be that the DLLs that you need are in the Core Components package in fact and the Automation Wrapper is just sample code.
https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/samples-and-tools-classic/core-components/